# Ubuntu 17.10 freeze when external Mouse is used

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 17.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and I like it because a lot of tablet features from my HP Elite x2 1012 are supported now quite well.
But when I am using my Ultrathin Touch Mouse from Logitech there is some undeterministic behavior and the system freezes after some time. I have used the same device with other releases of Ubuntu before and I had no problems until upgrading to 17.10. Are there any hints how to fix this?

Update: I switched to a normal mouse connected via USB and again a freeze occured. I'm not really sure that it has something to do with the mouse but until now it did not happen when I used the touchscreeen only or the touchpad which is intergrated into the detachable keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Some regular updates later the problem does not occur any more.